# Not able to get colorN to work in conky

Tags: conky

I have been trying out different Linux distribution options and it seems Conky has some different configurations between them. So while this `conky.conf` file worked before, it is no longer working. The problem seems to be the `colorN` options to predefine colors and use them later. I am guessing I am defining them correctly but maybe the way they are called is wrong? below is my `conky.conf` file. My Conky version is 1.10.1.

```
conky.config = {

background = false,
update_interval = 3.0,    
cpu_avg_samples = 2,
net_avg_samples = 2,
override_utf8_locale = true,
no_buffers = true,
out_to_console = false,
out_to_stderr = false,

own_window = true,
own_window_class = 'Conky',
own_window_type = 'dock',
alignment = 'top_right',
border_width = 1,
gap_x = 0,
gap_y = 25,
minimum_height = 5,
minimum_width = 5,


draw_borders = false,
draw_graph_borders = true,
draw_outline = false,
draw_shades = false,


use_xft = true,
font = 'DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12',
extra_newline = false,
uppercase = false,
use_spacer = 'none',

default_color = 333333,


color0 = ff3333,
color1 = 818181
}
conky.text = [[
${font Roboto:bold:size=10}${color0}SYSTEM INFO ${color1}  ${hr 2}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Uptime       ${alignr 0}${color1}  ${uptime_short}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Hostname     ${alignr}  ${nodename}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Kernel       ${alignr}  $kernel
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Network      ${alignr}  ${addr eno1} 
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Distribution ${alignr}  ${execi 60 lsb_release -d | cut -f 2| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}CPU          ${alignr 0}${color1}${execi 1000 cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | sed -e 's/model name.*: //'| uniq | cut -c 9-26} ${freq_g cpu0}Ghz
${font Roboto:bold:size=10}${color0}Memmory${color1}  ${hr 2}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}RAM ${goto 220}$mem / $memmax $alignr $memperc%
${goto 95}$membar
${font Roboto:bold:size=10}${color0}HDD${color1}  ${hr 2}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}File systems ${goto 220} ${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /} $alignr ${fs_free_perc /}%
${goto 95}${fs_bar /}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1} File Storage ${goto 220} ${fs_used /var/store/files} / ${fs_size /var/store/files} $alignr ${fs_free_perc /var/store/files}%
${goto 95}${fs_bar /var/store/files/}
${font Roboto:bold:size=10}${color0} Processes ${color1}  ${hr 2}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${color1} NAME ${goto 200 } PID ${goto 250 } CPU% ${goto 300 } MEM%
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 1} ${goto 200} ${top pid 1} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 1} ${goto 300} ${top mem 1}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 2} ${goto 200} ${top pid 2} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 2} ${goto 300} ${top mem 2}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 3} ${goto 200} ${top pid 3} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 3} ${goto 300} ${top mem 3}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 4} ${goto 200} ${top pid 4} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 4} ${goto 300} ${top mem 4}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 5} ${goto 200} ${top pid 5} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 5} ${goto 300} ${top mem 5}
${font Roboto:bold:size=8} ${goto 95} ${top name 6} ${goto 200} ${top pid 6} ${goto 250} ${top cpu 6} ${goto 300} ${top mem 6}
]]
```

Comment: You can install the earlier version of conky when it last worked and then "pin" the package at that version so it's not automatically updated by Ubuntu. For example `1.10` broke my script so I pinned it at `1.9`. Also some of my colors are: # blue
`color1 1EB5FF`
# light blue
`color2 30DDFB`
# dark blue
`color3 0090ff`
# lime
`color4 98FF76`

Comment: I found that if I use something like `${color green} $nodename_short` it works for me but cant get it to "set" colors as in `$color1`.. You have to add the  `${color green} ` to each line you want green or `${color ff3333} ` for your red I'm using version 1.10.1